# After using Selenium on macOS, Chrome isn't the same

Tags: macos, selenium, google-chrome

I installed selenium and used a python program to run chrome using selenium on my MacBook Air. Before there was an error on selenium, and after installing *googlechrome* drivers for selenium and creating a `PATH` using terminal, it opened a separate google chrome page that showed `Chrome is being controlled by automated test software.`

After around 30 minutes of running python and using selenium, I saved and closed out of everything.

In the next 2 minutes, I reopened Google Chrome to search something about web scraping, and the browser was the same one used by selenium. It still showed the `Chrome is being controlled by automated test software` notice, and there was a **Chrome Automation Extension**.

I tried:

- logging in and syncing, but syncing was not available.
- opening Google Chrome from application folder and dock, but nothing changed
- deleting Google Chrome and reinstalling, but nothing changed

I don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/26051/chrome-driver-2-28-chrome-is-being-controlled-by-automated-test-software-noti

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm not trying to remove the notification. I'm trying to find out how to change google chrome back to normal (including all my extensions, bookmarks, history, etc.)

Comment: have u added any optional parameters like "user-data-dir" & pointed it your base profile while launching the driver instance?

Comment: _...I saved and closed out..._ What did you exactly save and how and why? What is your exact usecase?

Comment: @DebanjanB, I saved and closed out of IDLE and chrome, before chrome was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I found out that the chromedriver was still running in the background. After I closed it using activity monitor, the problem was solved.